# Группировка по месяцам даты SQL

Tags: sql, delphi, ms-access

Есть некая таблица с датами и прочей инфой. необходимо сгруппировать инфу только по месяцам. Вот что я попробовал

```
Select наименование, month(дата)
FROM таблица1
Group by month(дата), наименование
```

Данный код группирует, однако только если дата полностью совпадает. Мне необходимо, что бы группировка происходила только по месяцам, то есть записей должно быть всего 12. В чем я ошибся?

Comment: укажите какую СУБД используете

Comment: в подобном случае я формировал поле типа дата на основании которого делал группировку, в [tag:mssql] это выглядело бы как то так: `DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(Created), MONTH(Created), 1)`

Comment: @Bald Работаю среде deplhi. Использую Access. Попробовал вот  что 'SELECT DATE_FORMAT(дата, '%d.%m.%Y') FROM таблица1 GROUP BY дата' выдает ошибку неопределенная функция date format

Comment: @4per Access из Delphi

Comment: Подскажите, а цель вашей группировки? Из запроса не видно что вы хотите, может 12 записей у вас не получается, потому что уникальных наименований больше?

Comment: добавьте в вопрос пример исходных данных и то что Вы хотите видеть в итоге, потому что не совсем понятно как Вы хотите поступить с данными одного месяца(например пусть будет май) но за разные года(2015,2016)

Comment: @bald таблица продажи. необходимо сделать анализ продаж по месяцам. 01.15 02.15 ....12.15. и в каждом месяце указывается сумма продаж, в примере неправильно указал имя поля. не наименование а колличество

Comment: @ 4per таблица продажи. необходимо сделать анализ продаж по месяцам. 01.15 02.15 ....12.15. и в каждом месяце указывается сумма продаж

Comment: Группировку можно делать только в том случае, если используется минимум хотя бы одна агрегатная функция(count(), max(), min(), ...).

Comment: вы наверно хотели сказать "Группировку **целесообразно**  делать" . Потому что группировку **можно** делать, даже если не используется ни одна функция

Comment: в точку, извиняюсь.

Comment: Очень странно. Текст запроса верный. Попробуйте выполнить запрос непосредственно в конструкторе запросов БД. Единственная поправка - имя поля, совпадающее с зарезервированным словом (дата), а ещё лучше - всю кириллицу,- необходимо обрамить квадратными скобками:
Select [наименование], month([дата])
FROM [таблица1]
Group by month([дата]), [наименование];

Answer (score 1):

Ни в чём не ошибся, если нужен анализ продаж по месяцам, то там и так будет одна из агрегатных функций или `COUNT` или `SUM` и приведённый код будет нормально работать. Если работает только, если дата полностью совпадает, значит не правильно выделяете месяц.
Тонкостей MS-Access не помню, а в PostgreSQL это будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
SELECT month, COUNT(*) FROM art --Или SUM(fieldname)
JOIN LATERAL EXTRACT(MONTH FROM дата) month ON TRUE --Просто чтобы не писать то же самое в GROUP BY
WHERE дата IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY month
ORDER BY month
```

Ну а если всё-таки `Наименование`, то естественно записей будет не 12, а будет зависеть от количества различный наименований проданных в данные месяца.
Хотя, если из Delphi, то это даже удобнее будет, там в табличке группировку сделаете по месяцам и будет плюсиком красиво разворачиваться каждый месяц с суммой в `footer`